# Flush cache does not call custom theme functions

Tags: 7, caching, theming

I have a Drupal 7 theme which is child of Bootstrap theme. When I flush cache from *Configuration > Development > Performance*, the primary menu disappears and the design of a custom menu breaks; when I flush cache from site's homepage using the the *Flush all cache* link, they show perfectly.

I found out that when I am in admin theme (Seven) and flush cache, the `bootstrap_preprocess_page()` function does not get called. In fact, no custom theme functions are called. That's why the page breaks.

I could not find the reason why this is happening. Can anyone please help me to find out the issue?

Comment: Preprocess functions are only called for the active theme and its parent themes. It is normal that, when the page is using the Seven theme, none of the Bootstrap theme functions are called. That is also true for theme functions and alter hooks.